# Why is there '0' in sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm executing a [Babelfy](http://babelfy.org/) program:

Here's the code:

```
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.Matching;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.AccessType;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.data.Annotation;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.data.BabelSynsetAnchor;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelSense;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelSynset;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.jlt.util.Language;

public class Example 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Babelfy bfy = Babelfy.getInstance(AccessType.ONLINE);
        BabelNet bn = BabelNet.getInstance();
        String word=" ";
        String inputText = "He has a passion for music";
        Annotation annotations = bfy.babelfy("3697a512-bfd4-427e-846d-9eb60f98c3bb",inputText,Matching.EXACT,Language.EN);
        System.out.println("inputText: "+inputText+"\nannotations:");
        for(BabelSynsetAnchor annotation : annotations.getAnnotations())
        {
            word=annotation.getBabelSynset().getId();
            System.out.println(annotation.getAnchorText()+"\t"+word+"\t"+annotation.getBabelSynset());
            //BabelSynset by = bn.getSynsetFromId(("bn:03083790n"));
        for (BabelSense sense : bn.getSynsetFromId((word))) 
         {
            if(sense.getSource().toString().equals("WN"))
                System.out.println("Sense: " + sense.getLemma()+ "\tSource: " + sense.getSource().toString());
         }
        }

    }

}
```

And here's the error thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://babelfy.org/rest?text=He%20has%20a%20passion%20for%20music&key=3697a512-bfd4-427e-846d-9eb60f98c3bb&partMatching=false&lang=EN&format=json
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.babelfy(Babelfy.java:95)
    at Example.main(Example.java:19)
```

Apart from the FileNotFoundException, why is there a '0' in the error at:

**sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)**

Does it imply anything else?

Comment: Because thet it the name of an internal method of the implementation.

Comment: [URL address](http://babelfy.org/rest?text=He%20has%20a%20passion%20for%20music&key=3697a512-bfd4-427e-846d-9eb60f98c3bb&partMatching=false&lang=EN&format=json) you are trying to reach points to 404 page (page not found).

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: Okay. So it is just plain Error 404 and doesn't mean anything else? Thank you.

Comment: [HTTP Error 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) and `file not found exception` is the same thing in this case. You are trying to get a resource (file) which does not exist by URL you provided.